# One question on map algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Kindly asking for any hints about the following questions:

1- Suppose, $X$ be an scheme and $g$ an finite-dimensional Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. We denote by $M(X,g)$, the Lie algebra of regular functions on $X$ with values in $g$ (equivalently, the set of morphisms of schemes $X\to g‎$). If $A = ‎‎\mathcal{O}‎‎_X(X)$, then proof that there is an isomorphism $M(X,g)≅g⊗A$ of Lie algebras over $A$ and hence also over $k$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would _define_ the Lie algebra of regular functions on $X$ with values in $\mathfrak{g}$ to be $\mathfrak{g} \otimes k[X]$ (assuming that the base field is $k$). What definitions are you using?

Comment: Whose sentence you want to know the meaning of?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, that's cheating :-)

Comment: By the way, there is nothing «equivariant» in the question. Maybe you can think of a better title?

Comment: After your latest edit: the fact that $g$ is a Lie algebra is irrelevant now. View it just as a finite dimensional vector space. Suppose $X$ is an affine space: can you do this in that case? (now there are even less equivariant things in the question... you should fix the title!)

Comment: What is the meaning of $k[X]$?(for an  arbitrary scheme).